# Why am I getting an existence error on predsort?

Tags: sorting, module, comparison, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to sort a list of paths by the distance it takes to complete them. The Prolog code I'm using is below.

When I call `sortRoutes`, I get an existence error from Prolog saying that `predsort` doesn't exist. However, I am using the sort module and that doesn't seem to change anything.

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

```
:- use_module(library(sort)).

sortRoutes(DistRoutes, SortedRoutes) :-
    predsort(distCompare, DistRoutes, SortedRoutes).

distCompare(Comp, E1, E2) :-
    my_nth(2, E1, Dist1),
    my_nth(2, E2, Dist2),
    compDists(Dist1, Dist2).

compDists(>, Dist1, Dist2) :-
    Dist1 > Dist2.
compDists(<, Dist1, Dist2) :-
    Dist1 =< Dist2.
```

Comment: Did you mean `:- use_module(library(sort)).`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It doesn't work even with that in place.

Comment: Also I assume your `compDists(Dist1, Dist2)` is actually supposed to be `compDists(Comp, Dist1, Dist2)`? With that change I ran your code just fine in SWI Prolog.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still got this error:
`uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,predsort/3),sortRoutes/2)`.

Is this existence error actually trying to say `predsort`/`sortRoutes` doesn't exist or does an existence error mean something else in this case?

Comment: It's complaining that it  `sortRoutes/2` doesn't exist. As I mentioned, the above code worked for me after I added the `Comp` parameter to the `compDists` call and I made up a couple of `my_nth` facts. Are there any differences between what you posted and what you are actually running?

Answer (score 0):

I think distCompare should be

```
distCompare(Comp, E1, E2) :-
    my_nth(2, E1, Dist1),
    my_nth(2, E2, Dist2),
    compDists(Comp, Dist1, Dist2).
```